# Конкатенация списков Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Имеется следующая функция на Haskell (не законченная):

```
    changeBattlefield :: Battlefield -> Point -> Battlefield
    changeBattlefield bf (x, y) = 
      let
        flankStart = slice bf [0..(y+1)]
        flankEnd = slice [(y+1)..lnlist]
                      where
                        lnlist = length bf
        medium = bf !! y
      in
        flankStart ++ flankEnd
```

Проблема заключается в том, что почему-то? при попытке компиляции получается следующее:

```
    Preprocessing executable 'ticTacToe' for ticTacToe-0.1.0.0..
    Building executable 'ticTacToe' for ticTacToe-0.1.0.0..
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/ticTacToe/ticTacToe-tmp/Main.o )

    /home/ilya/projects/ticTacToe/src/Main.hs:55:19: error:
        • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[Cell]]’
                      with actual type ‘[Int] -> [Int]’
        • Probable cause: ‘flankEnd’ is applied to too few arguments
          In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘flankEnd’
          In the expression: flankStart ++ flankEnd
          In the expression:
            let
              flankStart = slice bf [0 .. (y + 1)]
              flankEnd
                = slice [(y + 1) .. lnlist]
                where
                    lnlist = ...
              medium = bf !! y
            in flankStart ++ flankEnd
       |
    55 |     flankStart ++ flankEnd    
       |                   ^^^^^^^^


    --  While building custom Setup.hs for package ticTacToe-0.1.0.0 using:
          /home/ilya/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build exe:ticTacToe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
        Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Я так понимаю, дело в мисматче типов, но, насколько я знаю, функция ++ имеет сигнатуру

```
    (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

так что, проблем быть не должно. В чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что `flankEnd :: [Int] -> [Int]`. А имеет она такой тип потому что, видимо, вы забыли `bf` в `slice` передать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!